# Pros and cons of using type annotations in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, annotations

I was wondering the difference of using and not using type annotations(`var a: Int = 1` vs `var a = 1`) in Swift, so I read Apple's [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

However, it only says:

> You can provide a type annotation when you declare a constant or variable, to be clear about the kind of values the constant or variable can store.

and

> It is rare that you need to write type annotations in practice. If you provide an initial value for a constant or variable at the point that it is defined, Swift can almost always infer the type to be used for that constant or variable

It doesn't mention the pros and cons.

It's obviously that using type annotations makes code clear and self-explanatory, whereas not using it is easier to write the code.

Nonetheless, I'd like to know if there are any other reasons(for example,  from the perspective of performance or compiler) that I should or should not use type annotations in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely syntactic so as long as you give the compiler enough information to infer the correct type the affect and performance at run time is exactly the same.

Edit: missed your reference to the compiler - I cannot see it having any significant impact on compile times either as it needs to evaluate your assignment expression and check type compatibility anyway.